# How to plot data in Highcharts where time and value are swapped?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm getting JSON data from a server in the form of an array.

[[value, time],[value, time].....[value, time]]

But highcharts series data considers the first value as x and second value(time) as y. But I want time in x-axis.

Is there any way to directly plot the data in highcharts without manually swapping value and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide switchRowsAndColumns when plot it.

```
data: {
    switchRowsAndColumns: true
}
```